# App '\udccd' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: python, django

in django 1.8 python 3.4

Execute this command

```
python manage.py makemigrations myshop
```

[image: error]

My project not have this model `\udccd` , can't find any relevant code

I do not know why there error

but, runserver can normal operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your command line managed to pass in a [surrogate UTF-16 code unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF). The warning message is telling you that one of the app names you passed in to the `makemigrations` command is not available in `INSTALLED_APPS` but that Unicode character is clearly not a valid app name.

What happens is that your *command prompt* produced the extra code unit either before or after the `myshop` argument, passing it to Python in the `sys.argv` list.

You need to figure out how your command prompt is passing in extra bytes. Experimenting with `import sys;print(sys.argv)` should show the extra information that is being passed in. It may be that you are somehow typing it on the command line; you need to get rid of it if you want your command to succeed.